# Double cosets [Langs Algebra]

Tags: group-theory

Okay I am having a bit of trouble deciphering the language in this exercise. The problem is as follows:

> Let $\{c\}$ be a family of representatives for the double cosests (HcH'). For each $a\in G$ denote by $[a]H'$ the conjugate $aH'a^{-1}$ of $H'$. For each $c$ we have a decomposition into ordinary cosets
>
> $H=\bigcup\limits_{c} x_c(H\cap [c]H')$
>
> where $\{x_c\}$ is a family of elements of H, depending on $c$. Show that the elements ${x_c c}$ form a family of left coset representatives for $H'$ in $G$, that is,
>
> $G=\bigcup\limits_{x_c}\bigcup\limits_{x_c}x_c c H'$
>
> and the union is disjoint.

I am having trouble understanding:

1. How the first decomposition was formed I assumed that one would use what was proved previously ($G=\bigcup\limits_{c}HcH'$ where $H,H'\leq G$) and modify it a bit:
   $(H=H\cap G=H\cap\bigcup\limits_{c}HcH'=\bigcup\limits_{c}[H\cap HcH']=\bigcup\limits_{c}H[H\cap cH']$) to get a better result, but I couldn't really gain what they  originally obtained.Is there another idea he is trying to convey here?
2. What does $\bigcup\limits_{x_c}\bigcup\limits_{x_c}$ mean? It seems like an abuse of notation since taking the union of a collection of sets $\{A_{x_c}\}$  the first time will yield will yield a final set $B=\bigcup\limits_{x_c}A_{x_c}$ where, $B=\bigcup\limits_{x_c}B$?

Edit: Big problem, I think I found a counter example to the first equality: Let $G=D_4$, $H=\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}$, and $H'=\{e,a^2,b,a^2b\}$ then $G=HH'=HeH'$ so $\{c\}=\{e\}$. If the first equality were true then it would imply that $x_c(H\cap H')=H$ but since $|x_c(H\cap H')|=2\neq 4=|H|$ it follows that this isn't the case.

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, let $H_c=H\cap [c]H'$.  Now the $\{x_c\}$ is a complete set of left coset representatives for $H_c$.

For your second question, you've misread the notation.  It should read $\bigcup_c\bigcup_{x_c}$.

I believe I've found the source of your confusion.  You are right that your example with $G=D_4$, $H=\langle a\rangle$ and $H'=\langle a^2,b\rangle$ is a counterexample.   The problem is again a typo.  The equation should read:
$$H=\bigcup_{x_c}x_c(H\cap [c]H').$$

Comment: I am looking at it right now and it definitely say $\bigcup\limits_{x_c}\bigcup\limits_{x_c}$ but it is probably a typo.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the case.

Comment: I've added an answer to your first question.

Comment: Okay why is it that you can infer that $\{x_c\}$ is a complete set of left coset representatives for $H_c$ when there is no indication of how $x_c$ depends on $c$?

Comment: Well the $x_c$ depend on $H_c$, and $H_c$ of course depends on $c$.

Comment: Generally when given a subgroup $K\leq G$ one can place an equivalence relation on the collection $\{gK: g\in G\}$ by letting $gK=g'K$ iff $g=g'k$ for some $k\in K$ with that one can show that $G=\bigcup\limits_{\{g^{*}\}} g^{*}K$ where $\{g^{*}\}$ is the collection of representatives with $g_1^{*}K\cap g_2^{*}K=\emptyset$.With that said there really isn't a theorem I have read that says given collections $\{H_c:H_c\leq H\}$, $\{x_c:x_c\in H\}$, and $\{c\}$, where the latter is a collection of representations of double cosets and the former 2 depend on the latter then$H=\bigcup_{x_i}x_i H_i$